# Find the derivative of norm squared

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

Suppose I have the following expression
$||y-w||^2$ where y and w is a singular coordinate in the x-y plane.

I need to compute the derivative of this norm squared value and here is my approach.

According to (118) from [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~piyush/teaching/matrix-cookbook.pdf), the derivative of the norm is
$\frac{y-w}{||y-w||}$, therefore would it be safe to say for my problem it would become
2$||y-w||\cdot\frac{y-w}{||y-w||}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $v:=y-w$ so, using the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta),$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\Vert v\Vert^2=\frac{\partial}{\partial v_i}\sum_j v_j^2=\sum_j 2v_j\delta_{ij}=2v_i,$$i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert^2=2v$. It's in fact easier to differentiate the norm starting from differentiating the squared norm than the reverse, since $$\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert^2}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert}=\frac{\partial\Vert v\Vert^2}{\partial\Vert v\Vert}=2\Vert v\Vert.$$

Comment: Thanks for the that, if the question was modified to $\frac{\delta}{\delta ||y-w||^2}$ instead what would the working out look like?

Comment: @theninjaman In such a variant question, what would you want to differentiate with respect to the squared norm? In any case, the result would depend on which other quantities are held constant in the definition of such a derivative. (By the way, you meant to use $\partial$, not $\delta$; the latter has [a very different meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)).

Comment: Apologies for that, noted for the next time. Let's say the question just became $\frac{\partial \times 1}{\partial ||y-w||^2} $, can I use the property that  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \times \frac{1}{x} = (-1)x^(-2)$

Comment: @theninjamin I'm sorry, I don't understand the notation there at all. What does $\times1$ mean? Were you trying to say $\frac{\partial x^{-1}}{\partial x}=-x^{-2}$ in the second equation? If so, why is that relevant?

Comment: Sorry I meant the derivative of $\frac{1}{||y-w||^2}$ with respect to $||y-w||^2 $

Comment: @theninjaman Oh yeah, you can just observe it's $-\Vert y-w\Vert^{-4}$ as per your argument.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @J.G. Can you expand a bit on the final equation? I thought the question was to derive $\frac{\delta}{\delta y}||v||^2$. Where does the value in the denominator come from?

Comment: @pir The OP knew $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert$ and used the chain rule$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert^2=2\Vert v\Vert\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert,$$to thereby compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert^2$, and asked if this has been done correctly. Indeed it has, but my point was that, without using the chain rule, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert^2$ is easy to differentiate, so it's more helpful to use$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert=\frac{1}{2\Vert v\Vert}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Vert v\Vert^2.$$